# Server Side Validation Errors Not Showing up. User Goes to header location

Tags: php, validation

So I have what I believe to be a validated and sanitized form. When a registrar hits the submit button it takes them to the "headers" location. Even if the registrar did not complete input correctly,  it still sends the registrar to the "headers" location. From what I see it may be one of two things. Either the validation code is wrong or I am not displaying the errors out properly. I will leave my code below.

Below is index.php

```
 <php include("php/processuserform.php"); ?>


   <form method="POST" name="signup" action="php/processuserform.php">

   <input id="firstname" onkeyup="validateFirstName()"  placeholder="First Name" type="text" 
   value="<?php echo $valid_firstname; ?>" /><?php echo $error_firstname; ?><label 
   id="firstnameprompt"> 
   </label>

   <br><br>

   <input id="lastname" onkeyup="validateLastName()"  placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="<?php 
   echo $valid_lastname; ?>" /><?php echo $error_lastname; ?><label id="lastnameprompt"></label>

   <br><br>


   <input id="Email" onkeyup="validateEmail()"  placeholder="Email" type="text" value="<?php echo 
   $valid_email; ?>" /><label id="Emailprompt"><?php echo $error_email; ?></label>

   <br /><br />

   <input id="Password" onkeyup="validatePassword()"  placeholder="Create Password" type="password" 
   value="<?php echo $valid_password; ?>" /><label id="Passwordprompt"><?php echo $error_password; ?> 
   </label>


   <br /><br />


 <strong>Male</strong><input id="Gender" type="radio" name="sex" value="m">
 <strong>Female</strong><input id="Gender" type="radio" name="sex" value="f">
 <?php echo $error_gender; ?> 

 <br /><br />

 Click "Submit" if you agree to <a href="#">"Terms And Conditions"</a>
 <br>
 <input id="submit" onclick="return validateUserRegistration()" value="Submit" type="submit" 
 name="submit"/><label id="submitprompt"></label>
```

Now is processuserform.php

```
 <?php
 if($_POST)
 {
 $first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
 $last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
 $email = $_POST['Email'];
 $pw = $_POST['Password'];
 $gender = $_POST['Gender'];
 $data = array("$first_name","$last_name","$email","$pw",$gender);

 function test_input($data)
 {
 $data = trim($data);
 $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data;
 }
 //==========================================
 // FirstName
 if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/',$first_name))
 {
 $valid_firstname=$first_name;
 }
 else
 {
 $error_firstname='Enter First Name.';
 }


 //==========================================
 // Last Name
 if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/',$last_name))
 {
 $valid_lastname=$last_name;
 }
 else
 {
 $error_lastname='Enter Last Name.';
 }

 //==========================================
 // Email
 if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/', $email))
 {
 $valid_email=$email;
 }
 else
 {
 $error_email='Enter valid Email.';
 }

 //==========================================
 // Password min 6 char max 20 char
 if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]{6,20}$/',$pw))
 {
 $valid_password=$pw;
 }
 else
 {
 $error_password='Enter valid Password min 6 Chars.';
 }

 //==========================================
 // Gender

 if ($gender==m)
 {
 $valid_gender==$gender;
 }
 if ($gender==f)
 {
 $valid_gender==$gender;
 }
 else
 {
 $error_gender='Select Gender';
 }

 //=========================================
 $hostname="this is correct";
 $username="this is correc";
 $password="this is correc";
 $dbname="this is correc";

  $db_conx = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to
  connect to database! Please try again later.");

  if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
  }

  $select = mysqli_select_db($db_conx,$dbname);


 if((strlen($valid_firstname)>0)&&(strlen($valid_lastname)>0)
 &&(strlen($valid_email)>0)&&(strlen($valid_password)>0) && $valid_gender==m||f )
 {
  mysqli_query($db_conx,"INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password, gender)
  VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$pw', '$gender')");
  mysqli_close($db_conx);

 header("Location: pages/profile.php");
 }
 else{ }

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: I'm a little out of date with my PHP, but I don't see how `$valid_gender==m||f` is valid. `m` and `f` are not strings, which is what form input would be and I don't think you can use OR conditions this way, it's usually `field == val || field == otherVal`. Since the conditions are not grouped, your statement may likely be always equating to true

Answer (score 0):

`$valid_gender==m||f` isn't valid syntax for PHP conditions.

- `m` and `f` are not strings, and you'll need to compare a form input (string) to them
- The OR condition doesn't work this way

In PHP, this always prints "it's true":

```
$valid_gender = "s";
if( 0 && $valid_gender==m||f){
  echo "it's true";
}
```

It's the same as saying "if valid_gender equals m. OR f is true"

This is allowing your condition to always equate to `true`

Try this instead:

```
if( $valid_gender == "m" || $valid_gender == "f" ){
```

or even

```
if( in_array($valid_gender,array("m","f")) ){
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. So after reading what you wrote I transformed the "If" statement that housed the "Gender" issue to the following. Is this how you was suggesting to fix the "gender" issue? Also are you saying this "Gender" issue is what is stopping me from sending registrar's an error message of things they got wrong? Below is how I think you was saying to fix the code.

=========================================
if((strlen($valid_firstname)>0)&&(strlen($valid_lastname)>0)
&&(strlen($valid_email)>0)&&(strlen($valid_password)>0) && $valid_gender == "m" || $valid_gender == "f"  )
{

Comment: I did what you said (or at least what I think you meant) and it stopped me from continuing on to the header location. It doesnt matter if the input fields are correct or not it stops the registrar on the processuserform.php page. So in exchange for the header location page, it now stops on the external file I use to validate and sanitize the registrars input data. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd recommend initializing your "clean" variables to false, that way it's easier to check if they've been set. i.e. `if( $valid_firstname && $valid_email )`. You need to wrap "or" conditions in parenthesis but I recommend trying the `in_array` example I gave. If the condition isn't working, you need to print out/debug the values and figure out what the real values are.

Comment: Do I have to use an if statement to initialize variables to false or could the following work?
.....
.....


$a = $b = $c = $d = $e = FALSE;

Comment: Should I be using the isset function?

Comment: `isset` isn't needed if you're initializing the variables. Here's a little example of what I mean: http://pste.me/h9JqQ/. Also, if any of your validation expressions allow for spaces, make sure you're using `trim`. That's another reason not to use `strlen` to check for valid answers, it'll count spaces. If that's all someone typed, your validation would still pass. I suggest you use a validation/caging class: http://www.botsko.net/peregrine/